# Suggestions requested for writing ROS plugins

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to writing Rviz plugins. What would be the preferred method/ rviz class lists that I could look into for visualizing line segments, circles and beziers for writing rviz plugin?"

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238472/suggestions-requested-for-writing-ros-plugins/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to subclass *rviz::Display*. For examples (assuming C++), you can [download the RViz source code](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz) and look at the
[default plugin classes](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/tree/kinetic-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin).

**Edit:** also, go over the [Display plugin tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html). I personally work better from actual source code examples, but the tutorial may helpful.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1